# cmake: how to keep path to libraries during installation

Tags: cmake, installation, shared-libraries, ldd

I have some executable which depends on config files which relative path are setup in the source.

The executable links against a library, which is created in the same project.

What I am hoping to achieve, is having the executable working out of the box after installation, i.e. the installation would copy the executable, config files and library in a suitable location, and the executable would be linked to the library.

What I have for the moment:

```
install(TARGETS ${test_executables}  ${PROJECT_NAME} 
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/bin
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib)
install(DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/plot" 
    DESTINATION .)
```

${PROJECT_NAME} is the library, plot is the folder in which the config files are.

What happens after install is that all files are in the right place in the install folder, but the executable does not find the library.

ps:

I tried to add this before :

```
set(CMAKE_SKIP_BUILD_RPATH  FALSE)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH FALSE) # tried also with TRUE
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE)                                                
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib)
```

but this did not work

Comment: What output of `ldd <executable>`?

Comment: @Tsyvarev "libamd_clmc_dmp.so => not found", amd_clmc_dmp being the library compiled in the package

Comment: Hmm, variable [CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH.html) affects on [INSTALL_RPATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_tgt/INSTALL_RPATH.html) property only **at target creation time**. Are you set `CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH` variable **before** `add_executable()` call?

Comment: @Tsyvarev It works ! Thanks ! If you answer the question I'd be happy to validate it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is [INSTALL_RPATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_tgt/INSTALL_RPATH.html) target's property which affects on RPATH for installed executable. This property is set to value of variable [CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH.html)  *at target creation time*.

So, variable `CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH` needs to be set **before** `add_executable()` call for make effect on the target.

---

Most of global variables and target-unaware commands affect on the target only *at target creation time*.

There are exceptions, like command `include_directories()`, which affects on all targets created in the current directory. But *preparing everything before creation of the target* could be good practice.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue, and just added

```
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE)
```

before `add_library` and `add_executable` command, then it worked.

And you can find more details [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH.html).